# C char* printf issue

Tags: c, arguments, undefined-behavior, function-declaration

I am facing a strange behavior with a char* variable

```
user_message* parseMessage(char *incoming_msg, uint64_t size)
{
    user_message* msg = calloc(1, sizeof(user_message));
    printf("value: %s\n", incoming_msg);
    return msg;
}
void start_server()
{
    char* msg = "1|david|pwd|";
    printf("msg: %s\n", msg);
    parseMessage(&msg, 12);
}
```

The output :

```
msg: 1|david|pwd|
value: �[
```

I struggle to figure out what is wrong in my code.

Comment: You're passing a `char**` to a function which takes a `char*`.

Comment: If you don't see an error message for this code, then change your compiler settings so that you do. It's a total waste of time to try running any binary produced by an erroneous program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter of the function `parseMessage` and the expression used as an argument for this parameter have different types.

The parameter is declared as having the type `char *`

```
user_message* parseMessage(char *incoming_msg, uint64_t size)
```

while the expression used as an argument has the type `char **`.

```
char* msg = "1|david|pwd|";
//...
parseMessage(&msg, 12);
```

So in fact instead of outputting the string pointed to by the pointer `msg` you are trying to output as a string what is stored in memory occupied by the variable msg and what is followed it

You need to call the function at least like

```
parseMessage( msg, 12 );
```

Also it would be better at least to declare the first function parameter with the qualifier `const` if the passed string is not changed within the function

```
user_message* parseMessage( const char *incoming_msg, uint64_t size);
```

Answer (score 2):

`parseMessage(&msg, 12);` should be `parseMessage(msg, 12);`

The `&msg` means you're passing a pointer to msg, which will be a `char **` when the function takes only a `char *`

Comment: You are correct; It is my mistake. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

`&msg` yields a `char **`, or a *pointer-to-pointer-to-char*.

Both your `parseMessage` function, and the `printf` specifier `%s` expect a `char *`.

You don't need the [address-of operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access#Address_of) here

```
parseMessage(msg, 12);
```